# What is the syntactic function of 'more' in this sentence?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, comparative-constructions

> **With more than $3 billion in box-office revenue**, these fan-favorites rank among the highest-grossing films of all time.

In the highlighted text, how do we parse this?

Thinking about it, I can only assume that 'more' is a noun in this case. My reasoning is that it follows a preposition that needs an object, and 'than' already has '$3 billion' as an object.

If we compare this to another sentence, we can see a different parsing of comparatives:

> She is **better than him**.

In this sentence, 'better' is an adjective modified by the prepositional phrase 'than him'. Compared to the example above, this is quite simple.

Comment: Why is it different? "better than" and "more than" serve exactly the same role, where the objects are "him" and "$3bn in box-office revenue".

Comment: @DanielRoseman  They are both adjectives but one is comparative and the other is not.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's different because 'than' is said to be a preposition or conjunction, which — using the argument of it being a preposition — makes '$3 billion' the object. If this is the case, 'with' (another preposition) doesn't have an object, and it clearly isn't adverbial. 'More' can function as a noun — 'tell me more' — so I am wondering if this fills the role of object. The latter example, on the other hand, features an adjectival subject complement (better), which is modified by the prepositional phrase 'than him'. The object is clearly defined, and there is no room for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In 1), ***more than*** means: **an amount greater than** or *over* $3 billion. It is an adjective.

More
ADJECTIVE
Full Definition of more (Entry 1 of 7)
1: **GREATER**
something *more* than she expected

The function here is not a comparative. It is merely adjectival. It's descriptive: He has less than $10 in the bank. less than=not a comparative. It means an amount under $10.

With **more than** [over, an amount greater than] $3 billion in box-office revenue, these fan-favorites rank among the highest-grossing films of all time.

A comparative would be: She is better than him. [or than he is]

> [Merriam Webster_ more](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/more)

In "She is better than him:. she is being compared to him. And it is a **comparative** form of the adjective good. Something is good. One thing is better than another.

Comment: Would you therefore say that 'than' is adverbially modifying 'more'? This would make '$3 billion' the object of 'with'. In my opinion, this doesn't match anything I've read about the syntactic function of 'than', which is observed as either a conjunction or preposition. I understand the overall adjectival meaning, of course, but I don't think this answer provides the detail that I'm looking for. Feel free to disagree; I'm open to having my mind changed.

Comment: @MJAda "with [something: more than 3 billion] is a prepositional phrase. "more than x" here is semantically the same as: **With an amount greater than 3 billion** or **with an amount over 3 billion**. **more than, greater than or over** function adjectivally. They describe the amount.

Comment: Would you describe this as a case of ellipsis, then? The object of 'with' is omitted?

Comment: @MJAda No, nothing is elided at all: |with more than three billion dollars|| is a complete phrase. "With" is the preposition and "more than 3 billion dollars| is the object and "in box office revenue" is a second prepositional phrase.

Comment: That being the case, is it therefore not true that 'more' must be a noun? See this example: 'I want more.' This is evidence that it can be a noun (an object in this example), so — acknowledging the common syntactic designation of 'than' (a preposition or conjunction) — 'than $3 billion' is an independent prepositional phrase that elaborates/describes 'more' in an adjectival fashion.

Comment: @MJAda Frankly, for **me** and this is my opinion only, I have answered this question thoroughly. Final attempt: I want more.=more is a NOUN/ I want **more soup**.= more is an adjective. The rest of your comment above is mistaken.  "Than $3 billion" **is not a prepositional phrase**. It has no preposition. In fact, your entire analysis is inaccurate.

Comment: Respectfully, could I ask why? I have expressed that I think 'than' can be either a preposition or a conjunction (which is supported by most resources I can find online), but you have only stressed that 'more than' is an adjective. You haven't said why it's an adjective, and I don't think explaining that 'more' by itself can be an adjective is sufficient explanation (it's implicit). The function of 'than' is ignored, and the only way to refute my perspective is to provide reasoning.

Comment: You keep repeating the same thing over and over.  Sentences aren't parsed using single words only. So looking up single words often will not reveal anything. Look at the Merriam WebsLog In 
Definition of ter entry in my answer: more than = greater than. That entry says adjective. Here's the entry for MORE THAN in MW: more than idiom
more than: 
: to a great degree : very : extremely
Please call me anytime. I'm more than happy to help (out) in any way I can. That is not "more than 3 billion dollars"

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)